# Spring Websocket - How can I detect client disconnect

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I am new to spring

I have this class :

```
public class Server extends TextWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    WebSocketSession clientsession;
    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) {

        clientsession = session;

    }
```

I need to detect a client disconnect on clientsession.
implement ApplicationListener  but its not clear how I can register the listener?
do I need to do it in my web.xml ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`WebSocketHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/WebSocketHandler.html) `afterConnectionClosed` function is called after a websocket client disconnects. You simply need to override this in the manner that you override `handleTextMessage`.

```
@Override
public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus closeStatus){
    // your code here
}
```

There may be substantial delay between the client disconnect and your server event detection. [See details about real-time disconnection detection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26193072/4107809).

Comment: How exactly to override and register?

Comment: @MrD You do not need to register. The function is already called when the connection closes. Updated answer with simple override.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to override configureClientOutboundChannel and configureClientInboundChannel of AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer, providing your interceptor

Another way is using ApplicationEvents.

Both methods are described here: 
http://www.sergialmar.com/2014/03/detect-websocket-connects-and-disconnects-in-spring-4/

```
public class StompConnectEvent implements ApplicationListener<SessionConnectEvent> {

private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(StompConnectEvent.class);

public void onApplicationEvent(SessionConnectEvent event) {
    StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());

    String  company = sha.getNativeHeader("company").get(0);
    logger.debug("Connect event [sessionId: " + sha.getSessionId() +"; company: "+ company + " ]");
}
```

}

I hope that help. Let me know if I need to explain more.

Answer (score 5):

You can use listeners to detect when session is connected or closed.
More information about listeners you can find by this [link.](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket)

Example how to detect connected session:

```
@Component
public class SessionConnectedEventListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionConnectedEvent> {

    private IWebSocketSessionService webSocketSessionService;

    public SessionConnectedEventListener(IWebSocketSessionService webSocketSessionService) {
        this.webSocketSessionService = webSocketSessionService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionConnectedEvent event) {
        webSocketSessionService.saveSession(event);
    }
}
```

Example how to detect when session is disconneted:

```
@Component
public class SessionDisconnectEventListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionDisconnectEvent> {

    private IWebSocketSessionService webSocketSessionService;

    public SessionDisconnectEventListener(IWebSocketSessionService webSocketSessionService) {
        this.webSocketSessionService = webSocketSessionService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        webSocketSessionService.removeSession(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Spasibo Vladimir.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to achieve is maintaining multiple sessions. Something like this:

```
public class Server extends TextWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    private List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override 
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) {
        sessions.add(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) {
        sessions.remove(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) {
        // clientsession = session;
        // Send individual or broadcast messages here ...
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(textMessage + "!"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly to inject this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in your @SpringBootApplication or @Configuration annotated class

```
@EventListener
public void onDisconnectEvent(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
    log.warn("Client with username {} disconnected", event.getUser().getName());
}

@EventListener
public void onConnectedEvent(SessionConnectEvent event) {
    log.warn("Client with username {} connected", event.getUser().getName());
}
```