# javax.websocket - timeout for delivering message

Tags: java, websocket

I'm using javax.websocket API in my app. I send messages from server to client like this:

```
Future<Void> messageFuture = session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
messageFutures.add(messageFuture); // List<Future<Void>> messageFutures
```

I use async API because I really care about performance and cannot make server wait until each message is delivered, because server does smth like this:

```
for (i = 1..N) {
    result = doStuff()
    sendMessage(result)
}
```

So it is impossible to wait for message delivery each iteration.

After I send all the messages I need to wait for all the `Future`'s to be finished (all messages are delivered). And to be safe I need to use some timeout like "if server sends message to client and client doesn't confirm receipt in 30 seconds then consider websocket connection broken" - as far as I understand it should be possible to do with websockets since they work over TCP.

There is a method `session.setMaxIdleTimeout(long)`:

> Set the non-zero number of milliseconds before this session will be
>   closed by the container if it is inactive, ie no messages are either
>   sent or received. A value that is 0 or negative indicates the session
>   will never timeout due to inactivity.

but I really not sure if it is what I want (is it?). So how can I set a timeout like I described using javax.websocket API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idle timeout could cover your case, but it is not designed to. The idle timeout applies more to the case where a client makes a connection, but is using it only infrequently.

The more precise feature for checking a timeout when sending is [`setAsyncSendTimeout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/WebSocketContainer.html#setAsyncSendTimeout-long-).

Using both of these allows you to configure for the case where a client may leave a connection idle for minutes at a time, but the server expects relatively quick messages acknowledgements.

---

In my experience with Spring, the timeout implementation provided by Spring is not actually configurable. See [How do you quickly close a nonresponsive websocket in Java Spring Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26193072/4107809) I am not sure whether this is applicable to your websocket implementation.

Comment: Thanks! seems like this is exactly what I need, smth like `ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer().setAsyncSendTimeout(30_000)` should do the thing. Fortunately (or not) my app isn't built on Spring